QGIS: Finding random point in rasters transformed in shapefiles
I have a (for me) quite complex series of tasks to perform. The final goal would be to select a series of random points where to perform an habitat monitoring.
I am working in QGIS on a series of polygons with different shapes and sizes, and based on the different sizes I have to choose a number of random points.
How? Using these parameters:

if the polygon size is <8,33ha -> 5 points
If 8,33<size<50 -> 0,6 points/ha
If size>50ha -> 30 points

The procedure I have to follow is:

convert the shapefile of the surface in rasters with 15m sides
transform the raster in a point shapefile
select random points using the specified parameters and a minimum distance between points of 15m

I was able to convert the shapefiles to raster using Rasterise, found a grid of points based on the different squares, and then I am a bit lost.
Any suggestions on how I should proceed? I guess I can find a way to perform the different conversions from shapefile to raster to point shapefile, but I really don't understand how I could select the points differently in different sized polygons, adding a minimum distance parameter too.

May I suggest staying in Vector space for your analysis and generating random points for you polygons directly with QGIS?

Hi @LisanAlGIS, I guess I could do it that way (btw, didn't know about the possibility, thanks!) but for some reason the manual I am using - it's for a state agency - asks me to work precisely this way. It's a method derived from a US National Park Service document.

I understand. Can you clarify what you mean by "15m sides"? Is this your raster resolution? If so, then it seems like you could just select random raster cells and they will always fulfil your distance criteria. Treat the raster files according to their size which you can get from the pixel size and pixel count (without NA values since the raster has to be a rectangle but most likely your polygons are not).
Alternatively, GRASS GIS seems to offer a function which sounds simlilar to your problem?

To create the "random raster cells", if you do not want to use GRASS GIS (which can be integrated into QGIS btw), you could still use the aforementioned vector tool and then rasterise the output with the same extent/resolution as your polygon-converted-to-raster.

@LisanAIGIS, yes, by 15m sides I mean the raster resolution. Will try using that function (not really QGIS savvy, so I need to try and see how it works). One last question: what do you mean with Treat the raster files according to their size"?

The number of points depends on the size of your polygon. You can also get the size from the converted raster by counting all the valid pixel and multiplying it by the pixel size, which is 15m2. Or you get it from the polygon by calculating the geometry, it's your choice. You can also try this tool but not sure if it fits the bill exactly

You can generate random points in your polygons using the "Random points in polygons" processing tool (note this is not the older "Random points inside polygons" tool.
The tool allows you to set a minimum distance, so you don't need to rasterize to a 15m grid to ensure random points are more than that distance apart (but see note below).
You can use an expression instead of a single number of points per feature to meet your specified criteria.

If your data is in a geographic CRS or web mercator, set your map canvas to an appropriate projected CRS (a UTM or equal area projection) and use this expression.
CASE
    WHEN $area/10000 < 8.33 THEN 5
    WHEN $area/10000 > 50 THEN 30
    ELSE round($area/10000*0.6)
END

Else if your data is already in an appropriate projected CRS
CASE
    WHEN area(@geometry)/10000 < 8.33 THEN 5
    WHEN area(@geometry)/10000 > 50 THEN 30
    ELSE round(area(@geometry)/10000*0.6)
END



Note
You could then use those random points to select 15m polygons derived from the raster intersected by those points:

